# How do I heal my ship in No Man's Sky?

Tags: no-mans-sky

If my shield (or my hazard protection) fails and my body takes damage, I can get health from all sorts of things: wall dispensers, shiny artifacts, plants, helpful aliens, etc.

What about when my ship's shields fail and it takes damage?  How can I heal that?  (My current ship started out with 5 or 6 little ship icons below its shield bar; now it has only 2.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quitting the game and starting up again seems to have done the trick.  My ship was back to 6 little health icons when I did that.

Note: In this case my game actually crashed (because PS4), so I'm only assuming that quitting the game would have had the same effect.  (The save point that reloaded was from a couple minutes before the game crash, which was several hours after my ship was damaged.)

Comment: That jives with what I've read, that the only way to heal the actual health part of your ship is to save the game and restore it.

Answer (score 5):

At the very least, you can talk to the NPC in a space station, and providing you have the appropriate rank with them you can ask them for repairs, which should repair your ship.

Comment: I was wondering about that.  Are you certain that the "repairs" choice allows you to get *ship* repairs?  I've been forced into dialogues where I had to select whether I wanted suit repairs or multi-tool repairs (no ship repair option even though my ship was just outside).  My suit and multi-tool have apparently never needed repair (according to a text message after the dialogue), so I'm not even sure what those actions are supposed to fix.

Comment: I remember seeing a video wherein the alien specifically mentioned "ship" repairs. If I can find it, I'll link it below.

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed when docked at a planet based trade station (a multi platformed one) that when I went back to my ship the damage was repaired. Earlier in the same play session I'd stopped at a space station in hopes of recovering ship health and it didn't happen. I don't often get into ship combat,  and when I do I usually die, so this is the only instance of ship repair I can account for. Not sure if this was the actual cause for repair or if traveling a good distance (shields maxed, like how your health recovers) had played a factor into it, but I'm pretty sure it only happened after visiting the planet trade station. If you encounter a similar experience I'd love to know. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Park in a space station and let it autosave.  Then restore current saved game and your ship health will be full.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the answers given by the other answerers, warping also seems to repair ship health damage, which is fine if you aren't interested in exploring that system.